# How to Convert the object of ResultSet to Hibernate Entity Bean

Tags: hibernate, entity, resultset, jooq

I have a project, at the beginning of this project we choose Hibernate instead of JDBC for persistence, but we found out that Hibernate cannot apply for all the cases in this application, so we must use JDBC for persistence in these cases in which Hibernate cannot apply for. 
finally, we choose jooq instead of JDBC. so there are two kinds of technology of persistence in this application,that is,Hibernate&Jooq.
now, we want to convert ResultSet created by jooq to Hibernate Entity Beans. I have searched resouces about Hibernate but not find out anything. It seems that Hibernate hasn't APIs for it.

so, I have several questions !

1. How can I get the current context of Hibernate?
2. How can I convert the object of ResultSet to Hibernate Entity Bean by using this context(metioned at Question 1)?

Thanks All.

Comment: can you site some example where you could not use hibernate?

Comment: I'm sorry for my wrong description, I have asked PM just now and the answer is that we use JDBC just due to habits of some developers! now we use jooq to query and return a object of ResultSet, I want to convert it to Hibernate Entity beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at jOOQ's [Record.into()](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into%28java.lang.Class%29) and [ResultQuery.fetchInto()](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchInto%28java.lang.Class%29) methods? They support mapping jOOQ records to custom POJO's. You can either generate those POJO's with jOOQ directly, or define them yourself. If JPA-annotations are present on your POJO's, those will be used. Otherwise, jOOQ maps records onto your POJO's based on method naming conventions.

An example:

```
@Entity
public class POJO {
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "ID")
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}

// Fetch several of the above POJO's into a list
List<POJO> result = 
DSL.using(connection, dialect)
   .select(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .from(MY_TABLE)
   .fetchInto(POJO.class);

// Fetch single POJO's
POJO pojo = 
DSL.using(connection, dialect)
   .select(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .from(MY_TABLE)
   .where(MY_TABLE.ID.equal(1))
   .fetchOne()
   .into(POJO.class);
```

Now in the above example, you would be using jOOQ to execute queries. Since you are talking about transforming `ResultSet` objects into your custom POJO's, I'm guessing you're using jOOQ only as a query builder. Maybe, in that case, you could still use jOOQ to [fetch data from a JDBC `ResultSet`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetch%28java.sql.ResultSet%29) like this:

```
ResultSet rs = // [ your querying here ]
List<POJO> result = create.fetch(rs).into(POJO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have decided to use `JDBC`, you have to code what hibernate does for you. That means, you need to write code to read from the `ResultSet` and fill in the Beans.

Like,

```
MyBean mb = new MyBean();
mb.setValue1(resultSet.get...);
```

Now, forget the above, **If you are at the start of a project, I strongly advice to consider Hibernate. Start hibernate [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/quickstart/en-US/html/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I need a convertor more automatical.that is, this convertor can handle all the Hibernate Entity Beans, I want to convert objects of ResultSet to Beans according to the ORM settings of this Beans Managed by Hibernate. I think there must be a Hibernate's own class to handle it because Hibernate knows these ORM details of Beans.

Comment: If you are not using hibernate, then why do want to convert the results to **Hibernate Entity Beans**? Call them the a **POJO**.Hibernate knows the **ORM** details only when you are using it to connect the database.